# How to close the Online Payment Activity after a successful payment and redirect it back to the calling activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, payment-gateway, ebs-payment

I am using EBS payment gateway in my android application. It comes with a module which I have to integrate in my project. After doing so I created a Activity where all the payment processing happens. The problem is after successful transaction, the activity reloads itself and if I try to go to other activity via Intent, An error occurs saying `Activity has leaked window`. So how can I go back to my calling activity after successful payment and if possible help me with the work-flow.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue.There was a lack of info in the documentation of EBS payment gateway regarding the intent filter that is payment activity after a successful transaction.